# Writing memory scanner in python

Tags: python

(EDITED)

Sorry for changing the content.

I've change the code.

```
nameprocess = 'calc.exe'
def getpid():
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():

        if str(nameprocess) in str(proc.name):
            print nameprocess,'pid = ', proc.pid
            return proc.pid

PID = getpid()
PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400
PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010

process = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ,False,PID)
readprocess = windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
rdbuf = ctypes.c_uint()
bytread = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
for i in range(11):
    num = int('0x%08X'%(0x00400000+i),16)

    try:
        if readprocess(process,hex(num),ctypes.byref(rdbuf),
            ctypes.sizeof(rdbuf),ctypes.byref(bytread)):
            print hex(num),rdbuf.value

    except:None

print '----------------done---------------'
```

the result output is:

```
calc.exe pid =  4552
0x400000 4293587451
0x400001 4293587451
0x400002 4293587451
0x400003 4293587451
0x400004 4293587451
0x400005 4293587451
0x400006 4293587451
0x400007 4293587451
0x400008 4293587451
0x400009 4293587451
0x40000a 4293587451
----------------done---------------
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

but I want it to look like this

```
00400000   AE               SCAS BYTE PTR ES:[EDI]
00400001   0001             ADD BYTE PTR DS:[ECX],AL
00400003   0000             ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
00400005   0000             ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
00400007   01EE             ADD ESI,EBP
00400009   FFEE             JMP FAR ESI                              ; Illegal use of register
0040000B   FF01             INC DWORD PTR DS:[ECX]
```

just like debuggers do.
I hope that you guys understand what I am trying to do.
when reading processmemory, is 'rdbuf' gets all the information
what I want? What is it exactly getting from the process?

Comment: What does your code output at the moment?

Comment: the outputs are
--------------------------
calc.exe pid = 5656
f1e49fff1e4d9fff1e49fff1e4d9fff1e49fff1e4d9ff
f1e49fff1e4d9fff1e49fff1e4d9fff1e49fff1e4d9ff
-------------------------
printting same address over again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a serious error in your code. You are passing the `(const char *)"0xde2d6c"` to the `ReadProcessMemory` here:

```
    if readprocess(process,hex(num),ctypes.byref(rdbuf),
        ctypes.sizeof(rdbuf),ctypes.byref(bytread)):
```

The `hex` makes a hex string out of an integer; thus you end up reading the bytes from `calc.exe` process at the same location where the `"0xde2d6c"` string happened to be stored in your Python process, which, thanks to how the CPython memory allocation works, happens to be the same address all the time there.

You just were supposed to pass in the address, that is, `ctypes.cvoid_p(num)`!

Your code could be clearner written as:

```
base = 0x00400000
for addr in range(base, base + 11):
    try:
       if readprocess(process, ctypes.cvoid_p(addr), ctypes.byref(rdbuf),
                      ctypes.sizeof(rdbuf),ctypes.byref(bytread)):
```

Comment: `bytread` is the wrong type and size. It should be `bytread = ctypes.c_size_t()`. It happens that you're safe using `c_ulong` because all simple types internally use a 16-byte buffer, so there's no risk of writing to an unallocated address.  Also, without declaring `argtypes` the value of `ctypes.sizeof(rdbuf)` is limited to the range of a C `int` instead of the supported `size_t` range.

Comment: If you decide to properly declare `ReadProcessMemory.argtypes` and to define a `ReadProcessMemory.errcheck` function that actually raises an exception on error (as described in the ctypes docs), then please do not use `windll`. Use `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)` and get the last error on a failed call via `ctypes.get_last_error()`.

Answer (score 0):

When using `ReadProcessMemory`, you're reading some value at a specific memory address. What you're looking for, based on what you've said, is to *disassemble* binary code. I would use [diStorm](https://code.google.com/p/distorm/), a simple but powerful disassembler library for x86 and x64. Check out a simple example:

```
>>>Decode(0x400000, 'b800000000'.decode('hex'), Decode32Bits)
[(4194304L, 5L, 'MOV EAX, 0x0', 'b800000000')]
```

Note that opening the process won't be necessary, you just need to read the binary file content using the standard file input.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh, I feel stepping forward. (+_+)
I have a question for your answer.
when dissasembling a process that is not running.
Doesn't it mean that I would get a file memory rather than
a virtual memory?
Isn't that similar to PE View intead of Debuggers?

Comment: @KyungHoonBaek I don't think so, because you'll read a binary file to obtain ASM code, just like a debugger.